Cannot connect the app with CosmosDb in Docker
I was able to start and access(https://localhost:8081/_explorer/index.html) CosmosDb with Docker. But I cannot connect to the local CosmosDb from the app. In the app logs there are internal Docker IPs which are inaccessible. How do I change the app to use the correct URLs? Or do I need to change something in docker
Current WriteEndpoints = (https://172.17.0.2:8081/) ReadEndpoints = (https://172.17.0.2:8081/)
AppSettings
  "CosmosDb": {
    "CosmosDbPrimaryKey": "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==",
    "Url": "https://localhost:8081",
    "Database": "Test"
  },

_client = new CosmosClient(section["Url"], section["CosmosDbPrimaryKey"])
_client.GetContainer("Test", "Questions");

var result = await container.CreateItemAsync<Test>(new Test
{
    questions = new List<Answer>
    {
        new Answer
        {
            test = "1",
        }
    }
});

This code worked perfectly with the db in cloud, I just changed the appsettings to target the local one

show your code, you don;'t have to do this manually

@Sajeetharan I added some code but dont think it would help because I just followed the basic example

Try Creating Client as below,
using CosmosClient client = new(
    accountEndpoint: section["Url"],
    authKeyOrResourceToken: section["CosmosDbPrimaryKey"]
);

Check the documentation here
